# Attempting to read/write protected memory error while pinvoking a c++ function

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a C++ project X with calling convention set as __stdcall (/Gz) and a C# project Y.

I have defined a class myClass in BOTH these projects.

```
class myClass
{
    private:int mem1;
};
```

In the C# definition of the class, I have prefixed it with

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
```

The C++ function is

```
 _declspec (dllexport) void getLen(myClass* str)
 {
     printf("%s",sizeof(int));
 }
```

In Y, I have defined the function as follows

```
[DllImport("X.dll")]
private static extern void getLen(ref myClass str);
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
getLen(ref str);
```

where str is an object of type myClass.

Why is this error coming up when I run this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the `printf()` call: `"%s"` expects a pointer to a null-terminated string of characters, but you are providing a `size_t`.

Comment: Ok, I feel really stupid. It worked. Thanks! There was nothing wrong in my pinvoking.